# How to use scrapy request class

Tags: python, scrapy

Can some help me with making request using scrapy request class

I have tried this but it is not working :

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
url = 'http://www.fetise.com'
a = Request(url)
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(a)
```

error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "sa.py", line 83, in <module>
 hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(a)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmlsel.py",line 31,in __init__
_root = LxmlDocument(response, self._parser)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.py",line 27,in __new__
cache[parser] = _factory(response, parser)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.py",line 13, in _factory
 body = response.body_as_unicode().strip().encode('utf8') or '<html/>'AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode'`
```

I know about callback ..actually i first want to scrap the URL from the site then use them as a start URLs....

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is not working'. Do you get an error ?

Comment: Can you share the xPath for the menu you are talking about....

Comment: Here this is xPath it will generate the list of URLs `lista = hxs.select('//ul[@class="categoryMenu"]/li/ul/li/a/@href').extract()

acb = ["http://www.fetise.com/" + i if "http://www.fetise.com/" not in i else i for i in lista] + ["http://www.fetise.com/sale"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
import urllib
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from pprint import pprint

url = 'http://www.fetise.com'
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=data)

lista = hxs.select('//ul[@class="categoryMenu"]/li/ul/li/a/@href').extract()

acb = ["http://www.fetise.com/" + i if "http://www.fetise.com/" not in i else i for i in lista] + [u"http://www.fetise.com/sale"]

pprint(acb)
```

And this is output :

```
[u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/shirts',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tees',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tops-and-tees',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/belts',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/cufflinks',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/jewellery',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/lighters',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/others',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/sunglasses',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/ties-cufflinks',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/wallets',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/accessories/watches',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/boots',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/casual',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/flats',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/heels',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/loafers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sandals',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/shoes',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/slippers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sports',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/innerwear/boxers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/innerwear/briefs',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/deos',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/haircare',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/perfumes',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/personal-care',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/personal-care/shavers',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/apparel/tees/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/sandals/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/shoes/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/heels/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/flats/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/ballerinas/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/footwear/loafers/gifts-for-her',
 u'http://www.fetise.com/sale']
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests that you need to pass in a [callback](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) for when the request has completed.  The callback will have access to the response object:

From the docs:

> Passing additional data to callback functions¶ The callback of a
>   request is a function that will be called when the response of that
>   request is downloaded. The callback function will be called with the
>   downloaded Response object as its first argument.
>
> Example:

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    return Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                      callback=self.parse_page2)

def parse_page2(self, response):
    # this would log http://www.example.com/some_page.html
    self.log("Visited %s" % response.url)
```